# Special conformal transformation of $k\cdot x$

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, conformal-field-theory

I need to know how $k\cdot x$ transforms under special conformal transformations. I'd like to know how it transforms for a finite transformation with parameter $b$, but an infinitesimal transformation would also be interesting to me.

I know that $x$ transforms as $$x \mapsto \frac{x - b x^2}{1 - 2 b \cdot x +b^2 x^2},$$ and that the special conformal generators in momentum space are $$K = 2k\cdot \partial_k \partial_k - k \partial_k^2.$$ I thought about trying to use this expression to derive a transformation law for $k$ of the form $$k \mapsto f_b(k),$$ but I haven't been successful in doing that.

So I can see it must be true that $$k\cdot x \mapsto \frac{f_b(k)\cdot x - f_b(k)\cdot b\, x^2}{1 - 2 b \cdot x +b^2 x^2},$$ and I'd like to know the complete functional form here.

I used to be under the impression that conformal transformations leave plane waves $e^{i k\cdot x}$ invariant, but now I'm starting to doubt this. Any explanation of the geometry of how plane waves transform under special conformal transformations would be interesting to me also.

Comment: Special conformal transformations can be expanded as $IT_bI$, where I is an inversion, $x\mapsto\frac{x}{x^{2}}$, and $T_b$ is a translation. These look like they would have a nice expression in momentum space. Have you tried that?

Comment: I did think about that, but I don't understand how the inversion acts on momentum space. Do you know how that works?

Comment: No, sorry, just thinking off the top of my head and looking for some feedback, it does look like an unholy mess.